# How to display a contact list entry when typing the @ symbol?

Tags: java, android, regex, drop-down-menu, autocompletetextview

Following is the code that I'm using

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, result);
        AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView)
        findViewById(R.id.ContactDisplay);

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("@");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(textView.getText().toString());
        Log.d(textView.getText().toString(),"Msssssssssssssssssggg");
        boolean b = m.matches();
        if (b == true) 
        {
         textView.setThreshold(0);
         textView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
```

But I'm not getting any contacts by typing `@ symbol`. Should I have to use `key-events`?

Answer (score 1):

Try this pattern:

[image: Regular expression visualization]

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^@$");
```